# How to loop through a DataGrid to reassign cell text

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I need to go through each row in a DataGrid (not DataGridView) and change the text in each one at the click of a button. The purpose of this is to translate each option in the DataGrid.

I've tried simply reloading it, but this doesn't make any difference in the UI, so all the options still look the same.

```
Private Sub subLoadReportList()
    Try
        If gCurrentStrLanguage Is Nothing OrElse gCurrentStrLanguage = "EN" Then
            dgDefinedReport.ItemsSource = ActiveReports
            dgDefinedReport.DisplayMemberPath = "Name_English"
            dgDefinedReport.SelectedValuePath = "Defined_Report_ID"
        Else
            dgDefinedReport.ItemsSource = ActiveReports
            dgDefinedReport.DisplayMemberPath = "Name_French"
            dgDefinedReport.SelectedValuePath = "Defined_Report_ID"
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        strError = ex.Message & vbCrLf & " IN: " & Me.GetType.FullName
        Throw New LegalServicesException(ex)
    Finally
        If strError.Length() > 0 Then
            modGlobalFunctions.DisplayErrorMsg(strError, strError)
            strError = String.Empty
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview), [Binding to Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframework-4.8#binding_to_collections)

Comment: Iterate through `ActiveReports` and set the property of each item. Make sure that the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.